# In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'a.b.id';

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please help me fixing the issue. 
**My code:**

```
$dn1 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, '
select count(id) as recip
     , id as recipid
     , (select count(*) from pm) as npm 
  from users 
 where username="'.$recip.'"'
 ));
```

**It gives below error**

> Error: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT
>   list contains nonaggregated column 'omapm.users.id'; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Please help me correct this.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dn1 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, 
    'select count(id) as recip, id as recipid, 
        (select count(*) from pm) as npm 
    from users 
    where username="'.$recip.'"
    group by recipid, npm'));
```

anyway you should not use php var in sql command  .. this way you are at risk for sqlinjection.. you shoudl chek for your mysql driver for preparated  statements and binding param  ..